# How to read xml document with XmlReader?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml:

```
<doc>
****
<book>
    <author>Pete</author>
    <rating>4</rating>
    <pages>243</pages>
</book>
<shop>
    <></>
    <></>
</shop>
</doc>
```

I tried to read it with XmlReader:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
{
    reader.MoveToContent();
    //read some elements
    reader.ReadToFollowing("book");

}
```

But when i meet element `book` i dont know how to move inside, i mean how to read `author`, `rating` etc? And how to move to upper level again to read `shop` element.
I tried `ReadToDescendant()` but dont think that its what i needed.
Any advises?

Examples from comments dont helped me. I forget that i have a namespaces in document:

```
<doc>
  ****
  <book>
      <ns8:author>Pete</ns8:author>
      <ns8:rating>4</ns8:rating>
      <ns8:pages>243</ns8:pages>
  </book>
  <shop>
      <></>
      <></>
  </shop>
</doc>
```

So i use NamespaceManager:

```
  var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(reader.NameTable);
  nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns8", "namespace uri1");
  nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns6", "namespace uri2");
```

And read document:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
{
   while (reader.Read())
   {
       if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
       {
           reader.ReadToFollowing("book");
           reader.ReadToFollowing("ns8:author");
       }
}
```

But anyway line `reader.ReadToFollowing("ns8:author");` do not return `author` node.

Comment: You can check the node type and based on that, define more logic. Examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Here is another example: https://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlreader

Comment: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/reading-xml-with-the-xmlreader-class/

Comment: Easiest method : XElement book = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);  Then use xml linq to parse the book element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the right namespace in the `ReadToFollowing` method.

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
{
    reader.ReadToFollowing("book");

    reader.ReadToFollowing("author", "uri1");
    var author = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
    Console.WriteLine(author);

    reader.ReadToFollowing("rating", "uri1");
    var rating = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
    Console.WriteLine(rating);

    // and so on
}
```